# Integrability of random variable

Tags: probability-theory

I am interested in proving that
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} E(|X| 1_{|X| > x}) = 0 \Longrightarrow E(|X|) < \infty
\tag{1}
$$
where $X$ is a real-valued random variable.

In [this blogpost](https://www.randomservices.org/random/expect/Uniform.html#:%7E:text=If%20the%20random%20variables%20in,%E2%88%88%20I%20%7D%20is%20uniformly%20integrable.) the proof for the above implication ends with this statement:
$$
E(|X|) = \infty \Longrightarrow  \forall x \in [0, \infty) \; E(|X| 1_{|X| > x}) = \infty,
\tag{2}
$$
which is the same as
$$
\exists x \in [0, \infty) \; E(|X| 1_{|X| > x}) < \infty \Longrightarrow E(|X|) < \infty.
\tag{3}
$$

But I don't see why $\exists x \in [0, \infty) \; E(|X| 1_{|X| > x}) < \infty$ would imply that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} E(|X| 1_{|X| > x}) = 0$.

**Why is implication (3) sufficient for implication (1)?**

Comment: You may use the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Can you clarify? I cannot see how the sequence $|X| 1_{|X| > x}$ is dominated for all $x$ by some integrable function $Y$. I tried setting $Y = |X| 1_{|X| > x'}$ which is integrable for some $x' \in [0, \infty)$ by the hypothesis in implication (3). But then $|X| 1_{|X| > x} \leq Y$ only if $x > x'$.

Comment: And why is that a problem that $|X|1_{|X|>x} \le Y$ only if $x>x'$? We are taking the limit anyway, so only "large" values of $x$ are relevant.

Comment: Well, my understanding is that the dominated convergence theorem requires that all elements of the sequence be dominated by some integrable function, point-wise in the domain $\Omega$. That is, it requires $|X(\omega)| 1_{|X(\omega)| > x} \leq Y(\omega)$ for all $x \in [0, \infty)$ and all $\omega \in \Omega$ for some integrable $Y$.

Comment: All those theorem concerning limits require that the certain property holds only "starting from some point". In particular, there is no difference between $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \mathbb E[|X|1_{|X|>x}]$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$, where $f(x) = \mathbb E[0]$ for $x \le x'$ and $f(x) = \mathbb E[|X|1_{|X|>x}]$ for $x > x'$, and the latter family is dominated for all $x \in [0,\infty)$, but as I said earlier it is over-complicating, since anyway what matters is what is happening with large values of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is real-valued (rather than extended real-valued), we know that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |X(\omega)| 1_{|X(\omega)| > n} = 0$ for all $\omega$.  Furthermore, $|X(\omega)| 1_{|X(\omega)| > n}$ is a decreasing sequence of functions, so by the monotone convergence theorem, as long as $E[|X| 1_{|X| > n}] < \infty$ for some $n$, $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}E[|X| 1_{|X| > n}] = E\left[\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} |X| 1_{|X| > n}\right] = E[0] = 0.$$

Note that the existence of some $x$ such that $E[|X| 1_{|X| > x}] < \infty$ immediately implies $E[|X|] < \infty$ because $$E[|X|] = E[|X| 1_{|X| > x}] + E[|X| 1_{|X| \le x}] \le  E[|X| 1_{|X| > x}]  + x < \infty.$$

Comment: Regarding your last statement beginning with "Note that the existence...": I agree that $E(|X|) \leq E(|X| 1_{|X| > x}) + x$ is valid $\forall x \in [0, \infty)$. But I think the  claim that $E(|X| 1_{|X| > x}) + x < \infty$ is only true for some $x' \in [0, \infty)$ --- precisely at those $x' \in [0, \infty)$ for which $E(|X| 1_{|X| > x'}) < \infty$.

Comment: And regarding your first statement: I understand the use of the monotone convergence theorem, but I don't see how the requirement "as long as $E(|X| 1_{|X| > n}) < \infty$ for some $n$" is relevant or needed. Can you explain its necessity?

Comment: @harisf Yes, it is only true (a priori) for those $x$ such that $E[|X| 1_{|X| > x}] < \infty$.  But we only need it to hold true for one $x$ to get $E[|X|] < \infty$.  Then we can conclude it is true for all $x'$ because $E[|X|1_{|X| > x'}] \le E[|X|]$.

Comment: @harisf For the second question, the monotone convergence theorem states that if $(f_n)$ is a sequence of non-negative functions with $(f_n(x)) \downarrow f$ pointwise and $\int f_1 < \infty$, then $\lim \int f_n = \int \lim f_n$ - it requires integrability of a sequence element.  We can replace $\int f_1 < \infty$ with $\int f_m < \infty$ for some $m$ by simply looking at the tail of the sequence, i.e. the sequence $g_n := f_{n+m}$.

Comment: To your first comment: That's quite surprising, because we are saying that $\exists x \in [0, \infty)$ $E(|X| 1_{|X| > x}) < \infty \Longrightarrow$ $\forall x \in [0, \infty)$ $E(|X| 1_{|X| > x}) < \infty$. I think I find it surprising because we haven't used anything other than the trivial relation $E(|X|) = E(|X| 1_{|X| \leq x}) + E(|X| 1_{|X| > x})$.

Comment: To your second comment: I understand now that there is an additional requirement in the monotone convergence theorem when we are working with a _decreasing_ sequence! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: @harisf Yes, it is perhaps surprising that we can go from a statement being true for one $x$ to being true for every $x$.  It basically comes down to the fact that, since probability spaces have finite measure, the only way for a random variable to fail to be integrable is for it to be too large with high probability.  Once we know $E[|X|1_{|X| > x}] < \infty$ for some $x$, we know that doesn't happen.  Another way of thinking of it is that by looking at $1_{|X| > x'}$ instead of $1_{|X| > x}$, we're only adding places where $|X|$ is (relatively) small, so it won't affect the finiteness.